# How to read list of file present in Document Directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have some Dynamically created XML file present in my Document directory.So i want to read and store all these file name in to a NSMutableArray.

How Can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString* documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];  
NSError* error = nil;
NSArray* fileNames = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentDirectory error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
for (NSString *file in [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                        contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/path/documents"
                        error:NULL]) {
   // do something with file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
- (NSArray *)contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```

will give you the list of files.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this.. This will give you all file names from documents directory..**

```
   NSString* documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
                      (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];  

   NSError* error = nil;
   NSArray* filesInDocuments = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
                   contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentDirectory error:&error];

   for(int k = 0; k < [filesInDocuments count]; k++)
  {
    NSString *filename = [filesInDocuments objectAtIndex:k];

    [namesArray addObject:filename];
   }
```

Comment: Why not use `filesInDocuments` directly instead of re-add all paths to a new array?